# Load Pages with Framework7 and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, html-framework-7

I developed phone application using phonegap + AngularJS + Framework7.
My problem begin with the swap pages of the framework7.

Framework7 inject new HTML page to the DOM dynamically when user press on link button. hence , i have to use $compile and $apply() with angular to re-compile the new html part that injected.

but opening a window anumation is faltering while is load and compile same time.
my compile code is that:

```
//listiner for new page injection to DOM.
$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
    //on page init , compile the new DOM ijected.
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName(e.detail.page.container.className)).contents())($scope);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

There is also event called "beforeAnimation" .
i thought maybe to compile everything before the animation meantime to show to the user a loading spinner and when the page is ready i want to start the animation and show him the page.
but I'm not sure how to implement this solution , `$compile` and `$apply()` is sync ? if i have to use promise to make sure the animation of the new page will start only after `$compile` and `$apply` is done.

if you think about another solution i will be happy to hear that.

Comment: I suggest you check out some starter packages, maybe even the ionic.io project. Both Angular1 and Angular2 based projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
It very simple , all you have to do it is just config the framework7 to:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    domCache: true
});
```

Now on the pages you just have to mark it as "cached" like that:

```
<div class="page cached" data-page="about">
    <div class="page-content">
      <p>About page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and to open the page you just need to use javascript code:

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main')          

// Load about page:
mainView.router.load({pageName: 'about'});
```

It will be open the page 'about' inside the view.
This code allow top open pages that already found on the DOM, and not inject from another file.
that perfect for use with angular so like you know angular want everything on the loading.
Now you can use directive controllers etc.. on your page in framework7 without re-compile the page (re-compile is too expansive on phones).

I hope this will help someone else.

**EDIT:**
Docs: http://framework7.io/docs/pages-inline.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it can help you very much but maybe it can give you the right direction. I'd propose you to use ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) framework for your application. With it, you won't need to perform such kind of hacks.

The only thing, it could be challenging to integrate it with Framework 7. Although some people succeeded with it
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/35

Answer (score 1):

You should try to compile the views on pageinit event. Try this

```
Framework7.prototype.plugins.angular = function(app, params) {
    function compile(newPage) {
        try {
            var $page = $(newPage);
            var injector = angular.element("[ng-app]").injector();
            var $compile = injector.get("$compile");
            var $timeout = injector.get("$timeout");
            var $scope = injector.get("$rootScope");
            $scope = $scope.$$childHead;
            $timeout(function() {
                $compile($page)($scope);
            })
        } catch (e) {
            //console.error("Some Error Occured While Compiling The Template", e);
        }
    }

    return {
        hooks: {
            pageInit: function(pageData) {
                compile(pageData.container);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

and set this plugin while initialization of framework7 app

```
new Framework7({
  ....
  angular : true
  ....
})
```

For more details you can refer below github repo with fully working demos
https://github.com/ashvin777/framework7.angular